# ServiceStack vs StackExpress & non pre-release versions of StackExpress

Tags: servicestack-text

I was wondering if the only difference between StackExpress & ServiceStack is that the dynamic handling for .net 4, which is in StackExpress but not ServiceStack. (specifically in servicestack.text )

As such will StackExpress ever be non-pre release, if not and would the .net 4 dynamic features from stackexpress be available in the main servicestack.text library?

(the dynamic features in servicestack are necessary, but not having stackexpress as a release version prevents a straight package build)